# Way to invoke the Selenium IDE From a unix command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Is there a way to invoke the Selenium IDE From the Linux command line. I would really like to have a command that when run would cause the Selenium IDE to run the current test. (This way I can hook it into gvim's save hook and never take my hands off the keyboard)

EDIT:

I know how to get PHP unit or the like to run selenium. That works great for running tests, the problem is that right now what I am trying to do is use the selenium IDE as a macro. IE to load my app and navigate me to the part I am working on. That does not work well from phpunit because it reloads the page as soon as the test ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found you can do is use the unix command line tool "xdotool" to generate the click event on the button, which will run the script. Exactly what I wanted to do. This is the command line I run. (Its in a shell script)

```
xdotool search --name "Selenium IDE"  mousemove --window %1 153 65 click 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot run IDE directly from the command line, however you can use Selenium RC to run scripts recorded in Selenese (i.e. recorded by Selenium IDE) without converting them to a different language.

> Run Selenese Directly Within the
>   Server Using -htmlSuite
>
> You can run Selenese html files
>   directly within the Selenium Server by
>   passing the html file to the server’s
>   command line. For instance:
>
> java -jar selenium-server.jar
>   -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.google.com"
>   "c:\absolute\path\to\my\HTMLSuite.html"
>   "c:\absolute\path\to\my\results.html"
>
> This will automatically launch your
>   HTML suite, run all the tests and save
>   a nice HTML report with the results.
>
> Note
>
> When using this option, the server
>   will start the tests and wait for a
>   specified number of seconds for the
>   test to complete; if the test doesn’t
>   complete within that amount of time,
>   the command will exit with a non-zero
>   exit code and no results file will be
>   generated.
>
> This command line is very long so be
>   careful when you type it. Note this
>   requires you to pass in an HTML
>   Selenese suite, not a single test.
>   Also be aware the -htmlSuite option is
>   incompatible with -interactive You
>   cannot run both at the same time.

The above is taken from http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html

Comment: thanks, too bad, was not what I was looking for. Now maybe I can find someway to script the GUI so a command line script will click the right button for me, which at the end of the day will do what I want

Comment: One other option would be convert the script to another language and ovveride the teardown function so that it does not close the browser when the script has finished running.

Comment: That is more than I want to do for what was is basicly a way to automate my workflow. I may try to find a linux program to click the button from the command line

Answer (score 0):

For the Selenium IDE I don't know a solution. Selenium IDE is the user frontend for the Selenium Core.

But to run a set of working test scripts, you can use [Selenium Remote Control (RC)](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html). This is an API for the Selenium Core. It is available for Java, Ruby, Python, .Net/C#, Perl, PHP.

You can record a macro with Selenium IDE. Then you can export the macro to each of the supported programming languages. I used it successfully for Java:

- Exported the script to Java
- Wrapped the Java code with a JUnit test case
- Used a simple main method in a Java class to parse some command line arguments and to call the JUnit runner
- Started the Selenium Server from the command line
- Called the Java class from the command line

It should work in an analogous way for other programming languages. Compile Java or C# to an executable or directly call the Python/Ruby/Perl script.

The wrapping as a JUnit test case is optional. The advantage is that you can execute the Selenium macro also with any other JUnit runner, e.g. in Eclipse or with the JUnit Ant task.

Comment: For testing this works fine, but not if you are trying to use selenium as a macro recorder.

Comment: Why not record the macro with Selenium IDE, export the macro as a test script and call it from the command line? I don't see a difference between a test case and a macro.

Comment: There are 2 differences: first phpunit will not run it in my existing browser, but in a new browser instance (Without my firebug setup etc) and secondly when the script ends phpunit reloads the page, which kind of defeats the point. I want to load the page, go to the point I am working and then be able to interact with it

Comment: Two ideas: 1. Selenium offers -browserSessionReuse when starting server, see [short documentation](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSELENIUM-23). Alternatively [RemoteControlConfiguration.setReuseBrowserSessions()](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/1.0-beta-2/doc/server/org/openqa/selenium/server/RemoteControlConfiguration.html#setReuseBrowserSessions%28boolean%29). 2. Use [DefaultSelenium.selectWindow("<Window Title>")](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#selectWindow%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Some command line options for the server are only documented in the help pages of the executable, see this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/e297bee96740c0a?fwc=1). Since Selenium version 1.0, browserSessionReuse should be independent of proxyInjectionMode, see this [bug](http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-341).